# Any way to turn this into a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to wrap this in a function and cannot get it to work. I am wondering if it is because it is appending something to the body? But here is the script. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$('.showIt').click(function(){
$('body').append("<div class='show'></div>");
});
```

I would like to put that into a function i can call, but i cant seem to get it to work, This is what i have tried and it fails to work for me.

```
function create(){
$('body').append("<div class='show'></div>");
});
$('.showIt').click(function(){
create():
});
```

can someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra `);`.
Get rid of it.

Your first function is written as `function create(){ ... });`

Answer (score 2):

This will add a `div.show` to body when you'll click on a link/element with class `.showIt`

```
function create(){
$('body').append("<div class='show'></div>");
}

$('.showIt').click(function(){
create();
});
```

In your code you had a `});`when you should have `}` and `:` when `;` should be
Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
function create(){
    $('body').append("<div class='show'></div>");
}

$('.showIt').click(function(){
    create();
});
```

after cleaning up your code a bit I don't know why you can't do this.

you did have an extra `);` after closing your `create()` function though.